# Destroy all instance from a service (Release Camera using Wowza)

Tags: android, android-camera, wowza

Hi I have an app which is using [Wowza](https://www.wowza.com/resources/gocodersdk/docs/1.0/api-reference-android/)
in which I have also a service which I run a floating window in my service and in my floating window I have a video `WZCameraView`

I have successfully played my camera in the wowza `WZCameraView` however after I close my service

```
stopService(broadcast);
```

then I open the camera using intent my camera isn't available anymore or haven't yet release

My code for initializing wowza

```
goCoder = WowzaGoCoder.init(context, "RESTRICTED");
goCoderAudioDevice = new WZAudioDevice();
goCoderBroadcaster = new WZBroadcast();
goCoderBroadcastConfig = new WZBroadcastConfig(WZMediaConfig.FRAME_SIZE_1920x1080);

// start wowza preview/video
goCoderCameraView.startPreview();
```

It successfully play the camera/video wowza then after chat ended finish I dispose wowza properly using

```
goCoderBroadcaster.endBroadcast();
goCoderCameraView.stopPreview();
goCoderCameraView.getCamera().stopPreview();
goCoderCameraView.getCamera().release();
goCoderCameraView.stopBroadcasting();
goCoderCameraView.clearView();
goCoderAudioDevice.stopAudioSampler();
```

But when I open camera it says camera not available which mean camera is not successfully release,
I tried using activity for wowza video and finish it and it successfully release but using service it wont release properly

So my question is how can I release properly wowza camera on service or how can I destroy all variables inside the service onDestroy?

Thank you in advance.